# Circular reference issues in C# webAPi projects

Tags: c#, reference, circular-reference

I have a C# web api project whose architecture is shown in the following Diagram (ProjectA)
[image]

In the above diagram Controllers in Project A use the services of Project A in order to do the actual job and the Services use the Repository in order to read and write on the Database.
All of them use Autofac Dependency Injection.
examples:
Constructor of Controller that uses various services

```
 public DKMenuController(ITokenService tokenService, IUserService userservice, IDKMenuService dkMenuService)
    {
        _tokenService = tokenService;
        _dkMenuService = dkMenuService;
        _userservice = userservice;
    }
```

Constructor of a Service that uses the underlying repository for communication with the DB

```
 public DKMenuService(IRepository repository)
    {
        this._repository = repository;
    }
```

The various services are registered when the Application starts as follows

```
    this.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
 this.RegisterType<DKMenuService>().As<IDKMenuService>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Now I want to add another Project (named in the example ProjectB) that is simply a Class library and will be called from a ProjectA Service, will do something and then will use ProjectA's repository pattern and save data in DB.
The problem is that this design leads to circular references and the 2 projects won't compile.
There exists a similar question here [How to solve circular reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928387/how-to-solve-circular-reference) 
but the answer is not so clear whether it's correct.
Any ideas?

Comment: There's no circular dependency in your diagram. Can you please clarify where the circular dependency is?

Comment: @Enigmativity - look at the headers, the 2 _projects_ (columns) do have a circle.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - What headers? There's no circle in the diagram. It's a directed acyclic graph.

Answer (score 2):

It may be some work, but a fix would be to move the **`Repository`** into a new `ProjectRepo`.

Then have `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` both reference `ProjectRepo`, and then `ProjectA` can also reference `ProjectB` without B needing A.

Comment: That should not require any `redesign`. Just a little tweaking and refactoring in the implementation(s).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know what you are showing here is not a circular reference. You cannot draw a circle following the arrows on the diagram.

If the repository classes are on Project A Services then you have a circular reference but that's not drawn on the question. Having this in mind if that's the case move the repository outside Project A.

Comment: At class level nothing is circular, but at Project/Assembly level it would be?

Comment: I agree with Peter B. At project/Assemly Level there exists a circular reference. Let's say that there exists a ServiceA in Project A. This service A initiates a new object of Service B. ServiceB does some things and then calls Project's A repository in order to save in DB. If you try to build Project B, it will fail cause it needs the binaries from Project A for the repository Class. If you try to build Project A first, it will fail as it needs Project's B ServiceB class

Comment: @ChristophAdamakis - Project A doesn't have a repository. I don't see a cycle.

Comment: Repository is in ProjectA. See my diagram again

Comment: @ChristophAdamakis - It appears that Project A references Repository. That's not the same as the Repository being in Project A.

Comment: @ChristophAdamakis - It sounds more like you are saying that Project B needs to reference the methods in Project A. It has nothing to do with the Repository (as both A & B reference the Repository).

Comment: O Yes Project B needs to reference methods in Project A, as the Repository Belongs to ProjectA. I hope it's clear enough now