# Class implements interface and expose it as property

Tags: c#

Do you think the following code create some circular reference?

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
       
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public IMyInterface  MyInterface { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass : IMyInterface
{

}
```

Comment: No It doesn't. Did you experience problems?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This sounds like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @MosiaThabo no I did not experience problems so far, just checking if it could be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you done it using Interface is the right way to do it. No circular reference will occur.

Here's another similar question answered here on OS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928387/how-to-solve-circular-reference)

Furthermore, here's another detailed example from [Tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-circular-references-in-Chash)

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not create a circular reference, your class can inherit an interface 'foo' and have another 'foo' that has different implementation.

```
public interface Foo{ }

public class Bar: Foo {}

public class Baz : Foo
{
   public Foo foo;
   public Baz()
   {
       foo = new Bar();
   }
}
```

Even if it is the same type it will work, if they are different instances.

```
public Bar: Foo
{
   public Foo bar;
   public Bar()
   {

   }

   //this works because they are different instances of the same object.
   public void AddBar(Bar bar)
   {
      this.bar = bar;
   }
}
```

Even if you have the same instance it shouldn't break, because that's how the Singleton pattern works, you create a static property that holds the static instance of the same class.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any circular reference. Indeed, you have two simple concrete classes that implements an interface. And one of them, `MyClass`, acts as a wrapper of itself, a very used pattern.

You can find this kind of wrappers in different design patterns as the Adapter,  or Decorator, where you maintain a inner instance of the interface to decorate with additional behavior or change it completely.

Also, simple wrapper can acts as a layer to isolate two coupled dependencies or as an anticorruption layer.